# No .rvm directory after installing rvm

Tags: rvm

I don't have a `~/.rvm` file even after I upgrade my version of RVM using:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

This command produces the following. How can I make sure a `.rvm` folder is created?

```
Upgrading the RVM installation in /opt/t/rvm/
chown: rvm: illegal group name
chown: rvm: illegal group name
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/ros/.bashrc /Users/roseperrone/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/ros/.bash_profile /Users/roseperrone/.zprofile.

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.io/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues run 'rvm requirements' or read 'rvm notes'

Upgrade of RVM in /opt/t/rvm/ is complete.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a `~/.rvm`, because you installed rvm to `/opt/t/rvm/`.

You may either just live with that and use `/opt/t/rvm/` instead of `~/.rvm`. Or remove rvm completely and make a new install (which should then default to `~/.rvm`).